# eLearning website development by using PHP framework instead of an LMS like Moodle, eFront, etc

Tags: codeigniter

I want to develop an e Learning website where B.Tech students will come, explore the courses from various streams, see the videos, can take assessments, see their scores, improve their skills, can give their feedback, can chat with experts.

I do not want to use LMS like Moodle, eFront, etc.

How good it is if i use PHP framework like CodeIgnitor, CakePHP, Zend or YII?

Any advises & inputs will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any relevant experience in developing enterprise projects such is Moodle? If answer is no, sum all code lines there and tell us what you have (also show the code) so far.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to answer without knowing exactly your system requirements, so I'll give you a general response regarding the preferred frameworks in 2015: http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-framework-2015-sitepoint-survey-results/

As you can see, Laravel is the most popular framework nowadays, so you should be able to find a lot of resources/modules/components that may speed your development.

But then again, you may want to evaluate each of these frameworks against your requirements, your desired PHP version, performance in your servers and your PHP knowledge and select the framework that best fits you.  To get you started, here's a sample review done by someone in 2013:

http://mavrck.com/blog/2013/01/ive-evaluated-php-frameworks-and-the-answer-is-laravel/